# Spring BOOT security : Custom login page is never authenticating

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm developing a web app with spring boot. I have used spring boot security.

**If I use spring boot default login page, Authentication works as expected**

*But It doesnt work with custom login page*.

**I'm getting redirected to login page in case I use custom login page while configuring http endpoint** in websecurity.java

Sharing the sample code and my diagnosis below.

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class)
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/loginPage")
                .permitAll();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
    }

    private PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new PasswordEncoder() {
            @Override
            public String encode(CharSequence charSequence) {
                return charSequence.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.shopping.service")
public class ShoppingController {

    @Autowired
    private ShoppingService service;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/loginPage")
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register")
    public String register(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/submitRegistration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitRegistration(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        User saved = service.save(user);
        System.out.println(saved);
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

login.html :

```
<form th:action="@{/loginPage}" method="post" th:object="${object}">
    <div class="form-group">
<label for="username">Email address:</label>
<input type="email" name="username" class="form-control" id="username">
   </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <a href="/register" class="btn btn-default">Register</a>
</form>
```

UserDetailsService for user authentication from Database using crud Repo

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepo.findByEmail(userName);
        optionalUser.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Name not found"));
        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = optionalUser.map(user -> new UserDetailsImpl(user)).get();
        return userDetails;
    }

}

public class UserDetailsImpl extends User implements UserDetails {

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }

    public UserDetailsImpl(User user) {
        this.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        this.setAge(user.getAge());
        this.setName(user.getName());
        this.setId(user.getId());
        this.setPassword(user.getPassword());
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return super.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return super.getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: facing same issue it starts working after adding .csrf().disable()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the ids/names of the username and the password  parameter.

The default values are `username` and `password`, but you use `email` and `password`.

You can change the default in your security config:

```
//...
and().formLogin()
    .loginPage("/loginPage")
    .usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password")
//...
```

Note that you only need to change the one that is different from the default, I just wanted to show both methods.

**EDIT 1**

The second error is the form action, it must be the one specified by the `loginPage("/loginPage")` method, so in this case: `th:action="@{/loginPage}"`

Additionally the for attribute of your password label is wrong (must be `password` in this case).

I tested this and it works for me now.

**EDIT 2**

Spring security does not work like you imagine it to work. It intercepts the action URL of the form and redirects you to the page you tried to access before you where logged in. If you want to change this you can use `successForwardUrl()`

In your example:

```
//...
and().formLogin()
    .loginPage("/loginPage")
    .successForwardUrl("/home")
//...
```

Comment: Even after adding usernameParameter("email"), I see somehow the response gets redirected to login page.

Comment: Even changing name and id of email field to username doesnt work

Comment: Can you update your question on what exactly you did? Did you clean and rebuild your application? Additionally you should add the `@Bean` annotation to your `getPasswordEncoder` method.

Comment: It works fine if I don't use  custom login page, with spring default login page so  getPasswordEncoder can't be the cause of the issue

Comment: Yeah but its not a bean, thus not managed by spring, can lead to other problems later on.

Comment: Second error you mentioned is not so clear. I have login page which doesn't require authentication. Here, I have a form which on submit should get home page if credentials are correct. So, If from login Page,  I submit and I get redirected to login page (because of th:action=/loginPage)  then it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing so many of my doubts patiently. It works now. when I hit /home I get redirected to login page first and after submitting the credentials ,there I'm getting home page.

Comment: So if this solved your question it would be nice if you can accept the answer, see here on how to: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)